# How to ignore DeprecationWarning during testing in Pythons 2.7 - 3.5?

Tags: python-unittest, python-3.5

In 3.5 `DeprecationWarning` is explicitly set to show during testing.

My package is for 2.7 - 3.5 and uses functions present in 2.7 - 3.4 that were deprecated in 3.5.  Using the replacement method would be a pain since it didn't exist before 3.5, plus it isn't going anywhere for years (2020 at the earliest).

How do I get the `DeprecationWarning` silenced during the 3.5 test?

I have tried setting `PYTHONWARNING`, `warnings.filterwarning`, creating my own `TestCase` with `warnings.filterwarnings` in `__init__`, all to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setUpClass` was added in 2.7 and 3.2, and should be ignored in 3.1 and 2.6-.  So the best option is to create your own subclass of `unittest.TestCase` and add the `warnings.filterwarnings` code to the `setUpClass` function*.

`*`Don't forget to use the `classmethod` decorator on `setUpClass`.